# React component does not update with the change in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a cart data in this form

```
const cart = {
  '1': {
    id: '1',
    image: '/rice.jpg',
    price: 32,
    product: 'Yellow Corn',
    quantity: 2,
  },
  '2': {
    id: '2',
    image: '/rice.jpg',
    price: 400,
    product: 'Beans',
    quantity: 5,
  },

  '3': {
    id: '3',
    image: '/rice.jpg',
    price: 32,
    product: 'Banana',
    quantity: 1,
  },
};
```

In the reducer file I have a function `removeItem` that is being consumed by the reducer

```
const removeItem = (items, id) => {
  items[id] && delete items[id];
  return items;
};

case REMOVE_ITEM: {
  const { cart } = state;
  const {
    payload: { id },
  } = action;

  return {
    ...state,
    cart: removeItem(cart, id),
  };
}
```

In the component I am using this `handleRemove()` to handle the deletion

```
handleRemove = id => {
  const {
    actions: { removeItem },
  } = this.props;
  const payload = { id };
  removeItem(payload);
};
```

Now in the redux developer tool, the change is working effectively but the component view is not updating.

Comment: What does your component look like? How are you connecting the state to the component props?

Comment: Are you completely sure that the item is now missing from the store state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change removeItem function to below code

```
const removeItem = (items, id) => {
    items[id] && delete items[id];
    return {...items};
};
```

This is because component gets change only if reference changes. You can refer [this](https://blog.jakoblind.no/react-component-not-updating/) link for more explanation

Comment: Thanks. How can I delete all the items in one click?

Comment: Just send empty object {} ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a copy of the cart, as otherwise React won't detect the change, because it does reference comparison and you return the same object. 
Try to do the `removeItem()` in this way.

```
const removeItem = (items, id) => {
    let itemsClone = [...items]; // Copies all items into a brand new array
    itemsClone [id] && delete itemsClone [id]; // You perform the delete on the clone
    return itemsClone ; // you return the clone
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not mutate redux state, redux does not perform a deep diff check in your objects, when you do not mutate and create new objects, it is automatically detected as a different object, because its plain old js objects.

this would be good for further reading : [immutable-update-patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

so your `removeItem` method should be,

```
const removeItem = (items, id) => {
    let {[id]: remove, ...rest} = items
    return rest;
}
```

You can also use a library to do this, such as [dot-prop-immutable](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable) , which has `set`, `remove`, `merge` methods to do relevant operations without mutating the object.